# Vertical padding of responsive images

Tags: javascript, css

This **CSS:**

```
.outer-img-wrap {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    margin: 1vw auto;
    max-width: 192px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.outer-img-wrap img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner-img-wrap {
    background: #000;
    border: thin solid #ff9900;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

applied to this **HTML:**

```
<td style="width: 25%">
    <div class="outer-img-wrap">
        <div class="inner-img-wrap">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

produces centered responsive images in a table cell of the appropriate width. All images end up having the same width and thats what I want.

I would also like the images to have the same height in a responsive manner. So I added this **Javascript** to the page to update the padding.

```
function resizeImageElements()
{
    var imageElements = $(".outer-img-wrap .inner-img-wrap img");
    var imageElementsMaxHeight = -1;
    imageElements.map( function(index) {
        // compare the height of the img element
        if( $(this).height() > imageElementsMaxHeight ) {
            imageElementsMaxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    } );

    imageElements.map( function(index) {
        var computeTopBottomPadding = ( imageElementsMaxHeight - $(this).height() ) / 2;
        $(this).css( {
            "padding-top": computeTopBottomPadding,
            "padding-bottom": computeTopBottomPadding,
        } );
    } );
}

resizeImageElements();
```

The **Question** is: Can I achieve the same effect without the Javascript code; just using CSS?

**Fiddle** at http://jsfiddle.net/ybkgLq4d/

Comment: I'm thinking that CSS wouldn't be able to do it in this situation. In a sense you must know of those image Elements which is the largest and then determine how to make each of the other images equal in size. This is a rather easy task in jquery as you've shown. I believe that this is beyond the scope of css's capability.

Comment: The max height element computation is because I would like the same dimensions for all my elements. But as a `max-width` is specified a min or max height could also be specified, if that makes things easier.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the markup?

Comment: You could have all your images maintain a set aspect ratio using CSS.

Comment: @npage I do require variable aspect ratios.

Comment: @NeilMonroe I am not quite sure I understand? It is my page.

Comment: @gaitat I was just playing around with some options and didn't know if you had control over the HTML or if it was coming from somewhere else. Using a flexbox layout might get you closer without the script, but then your browser support is your limitation. Or, possibly work with the images as background images using `background-size: contain`. If you go that route, you would need to set a bounding box size. Lastly, if you construct your own table with `div`s and `display: table` and `table-cell`, you will have more control over the CSS properties you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not clear where you are taking those images from. If you're able to handle those images in a backend server (using let's say PHP, Python or ruby), you could always create a version of them using a fixed ratio, that way they will have the same dimensions when resized in your frontend. This would be my favorite option.

If you are not able or don't want to create a different version of the image, I believe your best bet would be using an element with a background image instead of the image element itself, and using background-size to fit your needs.

For example:

```
.outer-img-wrap {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    margin: 1vw auto;
    max-width: 192px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.outer-img-wrap .img {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
    background-position:center center;
    height:50px; /* or whatever height you want, you could use % value too relative to it's parent element */

    /* cross browser */
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    -ms-background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
.inner-img-wrap {
    background: #000;
    border: thin solid #ff9900;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Applied to this html:

```
<td style="width: 25%">
    <div class="outer-img-wrap">
        <div class="inner-img-wrap">
            <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/64x64)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybkgLq4d/14/

Comment: it doesnt seem to work if I replace `height:50px;` with `height:80%;`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep as simple markup and played a bit with `:before` and `box-shadow` and `calc`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pic {
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0 0 white, inset -2px -2px 0 0 white, inset 3px 3px 0 0 orange, inset -3px -3px 0 0 orange;
  max-width: 192px;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}
.pic:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 6px);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  top: 50%;
}

/* for layout */

figure {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
figcaption {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64">
  </div>
  <figcaption>text text text
    <figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
  </div>
  <figcaption>text text text
    <figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
  </div>
  <figcaption>text text text
    <figcaption>
</figure>
```